# How does trophy hunting helps in conservation of rare "Poop Bomber" dragon?

Tags: survival, dragons, deserts, preservation

In the modern days, World Wildlife Fund has promised a donation of a lump sum of $100 million to save a certain endangered dragon species found only in the Sahara desert.

The adult dragon weights 1.5 tons and stands about 7 meters tall are native to Africa and enjoys sunbathing, especially during sand storm whereby the sandburn helps to remove parasites off their scales. Sometimes they would take a mouthful of water by the river and fly thousands of miles across the dry desert to drench the thirst of their babies back in the nest, their clumsy bodies in the windy day spills mud all over the area hence they are also called Poop Bomber by the local.

Unfortunately in the recent years illegal hunting and trafficking of these magnificent creatures are spiking and plenty of rumors even suggested that this rise could be due to corruption within the government. The good news is that thanks to the introduction of trophy hunting, reliable statistic is showing that the "Poop Bomber" dragon's population are recovering which is a sign that controlled killing might be the remedy to all conservation of endangered wildlife.

A local guide informed that this crude yet effective method actually hits 2 birds with one stone, firstly the result is promising as observers counted more dragon's eggs hatched over the years and secondly it brings in revenue for the local community where essential resources such as water and vegetation are scarce. I am wondering how can trophy hunting contributes to the conservation of the dragon.

P. S: you may also argue the increase is just like a rainbow before a storm however such an attempt requires supportive materials.

Comment: maybe like killing the alpha male for example like alpha lion or wolf in hunting, where the male pack get a chance to copulate with the female and saving the youngling or hatchling from being eradicated by the alpha. though from your description this sound  like it will ruin the food chain though, assuming some animals there already adapted to the sand desert and the impact in ruining the sandbath or sandburn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is no different to the fight over legal "canned" hunting today**

Adam Ruins Everything did an episode on it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUA8i5S0YMU

Basically canned hunting upsets the do-gooders but in reality is good for the species and banning it increases poaching which wipes the species out, so by trying to save the species, people are actually causing it's destruction.

The reason why it's good is because it gives these animals a monetary value to the conservationists and local communities. Suddenly this animal which had no value or a negative value to the locals suddenly is worth huge money so instead of ignoring poachers and even becoming poachers, the locals actively protect said animals from poaching.

When the money is big enough, farmers and hunters buy the land required to raise and care for said animals. The canned hunters shoot the animal already preselected which is excess to breeding stock. Finally canned hunting is cheaper than illegal hunting and so the illegal hunting dies out due to the competition.

Everything might be distasteful and illogical but humans are stupid and greedy and this actually works better than banning hunting.

Conservationists in Africa are actively trying to get canned hunting legalized right now because they need the money to save these species. They're afraid that the bans will lead to poachers wiping the species out.

Answer (score 1):

They charge an arm and a leg for every trophy.  Then they repay any damage the dragon did during its life span, and split up the rest among the population.

This has to be more money than the people can get by poaching, or by accepting bribes from illegal hunters.  (In particular, the egg situation makes it appear that people were attacking the nests as the easiest way to kill or capture the dragons.)

Once trophy hunting makes tolerating dragons more lucrative than any other course, they will tolerate them. This has an advantage over other forms of tourism in that tourists who come to see animals generally want to see dozens, while trophy hunters are generally happy to just bag their trophies.